# Flutter: Infinitely nested closures inspecting FloatingActionButton 'onPressed' callback

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm really puzzled by why when I inspect a onPressed closure of a button widget in VSCode debugger I see a closure inside a closure inside a closure, and so on to infinity. You can see this in the screenshot below.

Can anyone explain to me what's going on here? This is just the default app and I've moved the FloatingActionButton into its own variable, which I'm inspecting at a breakpoint.

Is this correct behaviour and if so can someone explain to me why my closure isn't just a single one? Thanks!

-- Edit: steps to reproduce --
Make the default flutter project, move the FloatingActionButton into its own final variable, and change the closure to just contain a simple print statement.
Trigger the debugger once the button has been created and inspect it in the variable inspector and you see infinitely nested closures in onPressed property.

Code for button here:

```
final Widget button = FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      print("button pressed");
    },
    tooltip: 'Increment',
    child: const Icon(Icons.add),
  );
```

Here is the screenshot of the inspector.
[image: Inspector]

Comment: Hello there. Can you include the definition of `button` and provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? We need to check a portion of code to understand the problem and help you solve it together. At least how you initialized the `button` variable should be fine. You can `Edit` your question to include more information.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I've done what you suggested.

Comment: Interesting, event though the button is working correctly, the inspector shows arbitrary closures. I will assign the callback to a separate variable and check again.

Comment: Yep. It seems all the callback got shown up the same in the inspector.

Comment: Odd isn't it?  And I'm not just getting this happen on this one instance. It's happening for me in many different widget types and contexts. I'm a Flutter/Dart newbie though, and don't know enough yet to rule out my own inexperience as the cause.